# How to evaluate arguments of a function call inside other function in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, lazy-evaluation

I'm having trouble of understanding how to work with nested function calls and argument evaluations.

Here's a simple example. I have a top-level function `topfunction` with one numeric argument. Inside of `topfunction` I call another function `lowerfunction` which argument is a call to a function defined inside of `lowerfunction`.

```
topfunction<-function(x){  
  lowerfunction(myfun(first=x[1],second=x[2],third=if(length(x)>2) x[3]))
}

lowerfunction<-function(mycall){ 

  myfun<-function(first,second=0,third=NULL){
    print(first)
    print(second)
    print(third)
  }

  mc<-match.call(definition = myfun, call = match.call()[[2]]) 
  eval(mc) 
}
```

Inside of `lowerfunction` I capture the function call with `match.call`, and try to evaluate the call. But as variable `x` is only defined in the environment of `topfunction`, the evaluation fails:

```
topfunction(x=1:3)
Error in print(first) : object 'x' not found
```

I know that I could change the line

```
lowerfunction(myfun(first=x[1],second=x[2],third=if(length(x)>2) x[3]))
```

as

```
lowerfunction(substitute(myfun(first=x[1],second=x[2],third=if(length(x)>2) x[3])))
```

in `topfunction`, but in my real application the `topfunction` is constructed by the user, so the solution should happen somehow in the `lowerfunction` or even in the `myfun` level. But as they have already lost the information about `x`, I don't know if that can be accomplished?

In the real application the `topfunction` constructs the model using `lowerfunction` and computes its likelihood, whereas the argument of `lowerfunction` is a formula which can contain function calls, which will be evaluated via `eval`. These functions are only defined inside the `lowerfunction`. Also, `lowerfunction` can also be called directly, i.e.

```
x<-1:3
lowerfunction(myfun(first=x[1],second=x[2],third=if(length(x)>2) x[3]))
# or
lowerfunction(myfun(first=x1,second=2)
```

So solutions which add `x` to the argument list of `lowerfunction` are not applicable in general.

So the problem is that `eval` should take the definition of `myfun` from one environment (package namespace, or in this case from the environment of `lowerfunction`), and evaluate the arguments of `myfun` in other environment i.e in the environment of `topfunction`.

Comment: Exactly why are you trying to do this? Fighting R's usual evaluation rules usually ends badly.

Comment: I was thinking that as the `myfun` is not used directly, it would be better to not export it, but now that I think of it and see how hard it is to use it like I wanted, maybe I'll just export and document it normally.

Comment: Originally the whole idea of not exporting `myfun` was probably caused by the fact that its name coindices with the function from base R, so instead of masking issues I thought it would be more clear to just not export `myfun` Maybe I'll just rename my function then.

Comment: That sounds like a _much_ better idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward problem, but because you're doing *very* non-standard evaluation you'll need to create a new [environment](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) and all ensure all the objects you need are accessible from that environment.

```
g <- function(x){  
  f1(f2(x[1], x[2], if(length(x) > 2) x[3]))
}

f1 <- function(mycall, parent = parent.frame()) {
  # Parent contains x
  # New environment that contains f2 and inherits from the parent
  env <- new.env(parent = parent)
  env$f2 <- function(first, second = 0,third = NULL) {
    print(first)
    print(second)
    print(third)
  }

  # More idiomatic way of getting unevaluated expression
  expr <- substitute(mycall)
  eval(expr, env)
}

g(1:3)
```

I describe similar techniques in my chapter on [domain specific languages](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/dsl.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works, although you and Backlin are right, it seems easier and more clear to just export both functions.

Answer (score 3):

Lift `myfun` out of `lowerfun` and modify the `eval` call as below. When making a package, if you do not export `myfun` it will not be accessible directly from `R_GlobalEnv`, but it can still be called from within `lowerfun`.

```
topfunction <- function(x){  
    lowerfunction(myfun(first=x[1], second=x[2], third=if(length(x)>2) x[3]))
}
lowerfunction<-function(mycall){
    mc <- match.call(definition = myfun, call = match.call()[[2]]) 
    eval(mc, envir=parent.frame()) 
}
myfun <- function(first, second=0, third=NULL){
    print(first)
    print(second)
    print(third)
}
```

Example run:

```
> topfunction(1:3)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

**Off topic:** `myfun` can still be accessed from `R_GlobalEnv` by calling

```
getFromNamespace("myfun", "mypackage")
```

### Update

If you really want to keep `myfun` within `lowerfunction`, to preserve a conceptual point, you would need to merge the environments of `topfunction` and `lowerfunction` and evaluate `mc` there, but I do not know if that is possible (which it turned out to be, see @hadley's answer).

However, you can copy the variables not found in `lowerfunction`'s environtment (*i.e.* `x`) from `topfunction`'s environment prior to evaluation. Thanks to the lazy evaluation, this does not affect memory usage unless they are modified.

```
lowerfunction<-function(mycall){
    myfun <- function(first, second=0, third=NULL){
        print(first)
        print(second)
        print(third)
    }
    mc <- match.call(definition = myfun, call = match.call()[[2]]) 
    x <- get("x", parent.frame())
    eval(mc)
}
```

However again, since you do not know what objects the user will incorporate into `topfunction`, you cannot hard code it as above but must do it by extracting all *names* from `mc` and copy them via `assign`. It is possible, but I recommend you save yourself the trouble and export both `lowerfunction` and `myfun`.

Comment: Hmm, but if I do not export `myfun`, then using `eval(mc, envir=parent.frame())` looks for `myfun`in global environment, and doesn't find it?

Comment: Nope, it works fine! It appears `eval` looks in the environments of the `envir` argument *i.e.* `topfunction`'s enviroment, the package namespace and the global environment. Just tested it and made a demo you can look at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4243933/evaltest_1.1-1.tar.gz

Comment: In your demo package `lowerfunction` is not exported and `topfunction` is part of the package and is exported. But if you remove `topfunction` from the package and define it in global environment (as this is supposed to be function made by user) and export `lowerfunction` so that user sees it (but not `myfun`), then this approach does not work, as `eval` in `lowerfunction` does not find `myfun`.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. If you want the leave the definition of `topfunction` to the user, and allow him/her to include both `lowerfunction` and `myfun` in it, you must define them separately and export both. If this is not an acceptable solution, can you please explain why?

Comment: The idea is that the `lowerfunction` can be accessed by the user, but `myfun` is only used inside of `lowerfunction` (it has no meaning elsewhere), so I though that it does not need to be exported. But it seems that in order this type of construct to work, I must export it also.

Comment: In the actual application I would have something like `likfn<-function(pars,p) model(y~arcomponent(ar=if(p>0) pars[1:p] else NULL))` whehe `likfn` is the user made function, `model` is exported function which is visible as such to the user, and `arcomponent` is a function which is used inside of modelling function.